# can't install mysql on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I am unable to install mysql server on my linux-20.4 machine.I get the following error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.27-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have tried deleting and then reinstall several times but got the same result.Then i tried to manually install all the packages. But I got stuck in libaio1 and libmecab2. I did apt-get upgrade but still
get the error : Package 'libaio1' has no installation candidate.
This is the first time I am installing mysql.Also I am new to linux.May be I didn't delete existing mysql completely.Please help me install mysql.

Comment: You may find this helpful : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326298/installing-mysql-server-showing-error-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mysql-common and mysql-community-client-plugins both on a single command. It will fix the issue.

sudo apt install mysql-community-client-plugins mysql-common

Comment: Both of them are installed. But when I run sudo apt-get install mysql-server  I get the same error that the package have unmet dependencies. Is it possible that the issue is OS related and I need to reinstall ubuntu to fix this?